# Expected '[, kind: POLYMORPHIC'

Tags: json, kotlin, kotlinx.serialization

I am trying to get custom serializing to work with kotlinx.serialization like this reduced example:

```
@Serializable
open class KdfParams {
    var dklen: Int = 0
    var salt: String? = null

    @Serializer(forClass = KdfParams::class)
    companion object {
        override fun save(output: KOutput, obj: KdfParams) = TODO()

        override fun load(input: KInput): KdfParams {
            return KdfParams()
        }
    }

}
```

but I get:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: JSON at 369: Expected '[, kind: POLYMORPHIC'

    at kotlinx.serialization.json.JSONKt.fail(JSON.kt:525)
    at kotlinx.serialization.json.JSONKt.require(JSON.kt:521)
    at kotlinx.serialization.json.JSONKt.access$require(JSON.kt:1)
    at kotlinx.serialization.json.JSON$JsonInput.readBegin(JSON.kt:232)
    at kotlinx.serialization.PolymorphicSerializer.load(PolymorphicSerializer.kt:37)
    at kotlinx.serialization.KInput.readSerializableValue(Serialization.kt:243)
    at kotlinx.serialization.KInput.readNullableSerializableValue(Serialization.kt:246)
    at kotlinx.serialization.ElementValueInput.readNullableSerializableElementValue(Serialization.kt:441)
    at org.kethereum.wallet.WalletFileCrypto$$serializer.load(WalletFile.kt)
    at org.kethereum.wallet.WalletFileCrypto$$serializer.load(WalletFile.kt:13)
    at kotlinx.serialization.KInput.readSerializableValue(Serialization.kt:243)
    at kotlinx.serialization.KInput.readNullableSerializableValue(Serialization.kt:246)
    at kotlinx.serialization.ElementValueInput.readNullableSerializableElementValue(Serialization.kt:441)
    at org.kethereum.wallet.WalletFile$$serializer.load(WalletFile.kt)
    at org.kethereum.wallet.WalletFile$$serializer.load(WalletFile.kt:29)
    at kotlinx.serialization.KInput.read(Serialization.kt:209)
    at kotlinx.serialization.json.JSON.parse(JSON.kt:49)
    at kotlinx.serialization.json.JSON$Companion.parse(JSON.kt:59)
    at org.kethereum.wallet.WalletTest.load(WalletTest.kt:53)
    at org.kethereum.wallet.WalletTest.testDecryptAes128Ctr(WalletTest.kt:33)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:68)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:47)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:242)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:70)
```

Answer (score 0):

This most likely is due to how your classes inherit from each other. If you have serializable classes that all extend another class that is serializable this error can occur. Post your code to see if this is the error.